# Angular complains about a missing module which haven't been declared at allI

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to define two angular modules `myApp1` & `myApp2`.

And from `myApp1` I'm consuming a service of `myApp2`.

Here's what I tried in `JSfiddle`

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{saycheese}}
</div>
```

**js**

```
var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);

myApp1.service('myservice', function() {
    this.sayHello = function(test) {
        return "from service" + test;
    };
    this.sayHello1 = function() {
            return "from service - sayHello1"
    };
});

myApp2.service('myservice2', function() {
        this.sayCheese = function(test) {
             return "from service of myApp2" + test;
    };
});

myApp1.factory('myfactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "from factory!"
        }


    };
});

//defining a controller over here      
myApp1.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "myfactory", "myservice", "myservice2", function($scope, myfactory, myservice, myservice2) {

    $scope.saycheese = [
        myfactory.sayHello(),
        myservice.sayHello("abcd"),
        myservice.sayHello1(),
        myservice2.sayCheese("abcdefghij!")
        ];

}]);
```

But when I check **CONSOLE LOGS**, angular complains about `no module: myApp`.

The JSfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/3050/

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its the problem with the naming convention, you can't use numbers in a module name. I renamed them as `myApp1 -> myApp & myApp2 -> myApptwo`.
2. Second issue is you haven't injected `myApptwo` in `myApp`, without which you won't be able to access services of `myApptwo`

```js
var myApptwo = angular.module('myApptwo', []);
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApptwo']);

myApp.service('myservice', function() {
    this.sayHello = function(test) {
        return "from service" + test;
    };
    this.sayHello1 = function() {
      return "from service - sayHello1"
    };
});

myApptwo.service('myservice2', function() {
  this.sayCheese = function(test) {
       return "from service of myApp2" + test;
    };
});

myApp.factory('myfactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "from factory!"
        }
        
        
    };
});
    
//defining a controller over here      
myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "myfactory", "myservice", "myservice2", function($scope, myfactory, myservice, myservice2) {

    $scope.saycheese = [
        myfactory.sayHello(),
        myservice.sayHello("abcd"),
        myservice.sayHello1(),
        myservice2.sayCheese("abcdefghij!")
        ];

}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{saycheese}}
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously. Because i haven't added angular dependency, don't run my code snippet. Make changes in your's one.